# Indefinite articles for plural

Tags: grammar, articles

Is this sentence correct?

> I saw a gray and a black elephants.
>   (With meaning: I saw two elephants, one was gray, and the other was black).

Answer (score 1):

No, your current construction is incorrect.

It should be:

> I saw a gray and a black elephant.

That is,

> I saw a gray elephant and a black elephant.

The extra indefinite article "a" before "black" shows that you are talking about two individual things. Without the "a" before "black", it would be as though you are talking about seeing an elephant that is both gray and black.

Comment: Or *I saw gray and black elephants* (no article, plural noun). Which *could* mean I saw just one of each colour - but it could equally mean I saw *multiple* elephants of either / both colours.